# Intl.NumberFormat for Croatia

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make a format in Croatian currency kuna.

This is what I want to achieve: 1.509,90 kn
And this is what I get: 1.509,90 HRK

Also the best part is that Mozilla and Chromium are displaying it as it should.
Chrome is not displaying it as it should.

My guess something is wrong is iso standard for Croatia. I tried with Germany and couple of other countries and it works as expected. Maybe it should say something like 'hr-HR' or something like that. Mozilla has a different engine and my guess is he see's 'hr' and understands that I want lets say 'hr-HR'.

This is my code:

```js
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('hr', { style: 'currency', currency: 'HRK', currencyDisplay:'symbol' }).format("1221.5"));
```

How do I change the HRK to kn?

Comment: I ran your code in 2 browsers: Brave and Chrome, and both are showing the result: 1.221,50 kn

Comment: I get the results I want from Firefox & Chromium but I get HRK on chrome.

Comment: It seems that Chrome 97 shows `HRK` while Chrome 98 shows `kn`

Comment: I found an information (not sure if it's true) that node.js version 14 and above will display kn, node.js <14 will show hrk. However I can't control the version of node client runs.